# Cannot connect colab to my google drive as it doesn't appear when searching

Tags: google-colaboratory

From my google drive, I'm trying to connect google colab to my google drive without success.
Please, find below the steps that I took:

1. more
2. connect more apps
3. typed 'colab' in the search bar and I didn't find the app.

Thank you in advance for helping me out.

- While in `Drive`, click on `New` button (marked with a `+ New`) on left-hand side and select `More` > `Connect more apps`

[image]

- Then, by using the magnifying glass icon to `"Search apps"` and typing in `colab`, it returns no results

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Step 1:

Sign into the site thru the link https://colab.research.google.com.
From there, there will be a `Google Drive` tab with the ability to create new notebooks.

[image]

#### Step 2:

Then, next to the notebook, to the direct right of the `Last opened` column there is a small folder icon and clicking on that will bring you to your Google drive folder called `My Drive` > `Colab Notebooks`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are trying in correct direction, but Google has removed that option from Google Drive, you have to go via [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com) itself, and save to Colab Notebooks Folder.

From there you can open them into Google colab, but creating new notebooks directly from Google Drive is not available as it used to be in past few years